# Convertir resultado de consulta en mysql de string a int

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Saludos Mi duda es que al hacer una consulta el resultado de esa consulta lo devuelve como mysqli_result (string) pero lo necesito como int para realizar una inserción a la base de datos
Como puedo convertir el resultado a entero? o que me hace falta?

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump(($_POST));
    echo "</pre>";

    function obtener_id(){
        $db = conectarDB();   
        $autores = $_POST['autores'];
        $sql = "SELECT ID_USUARIOS
        FROM USUARIOS
        WHERE NOMBRE_USUARIO = '$autores';";            
        $result  = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
        echo "</pre>";

        return (int) $result;
    }
```

Comment: Tal vez estos dos enlaces ayuden: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008214/php-string-to-int https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-a-string-into-number-in-php/

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Qué resultado exactamente quieres obtener como entero y dónde lo quieres insertar? Por ejemplo, si se trata de insertar datos de una tabla en otra, eso podría hacerse directamente con una sola consulta del tipo `INSERT INTO tablaDestino (col1, col2, colN) SELECT col1, col2, colN FROM tablaOrigen WHERE ... ` En caso de que no convenga hacerlo así por algún motivo, y decidas recuperar los resultados en variables, tendrías que usar consultas preparadas, porque en primer lugar protegen el código y segundo tienen métodos para indicar de qué tipo es cada dato.

Comment: @A.Cedano estoy ingresando el nombre de un usuario desde un formulario, ese nombre esta almacenado en una tabla en la base de datos y estoy realizando una consulta para obtener su id. Al obtenerlo creo una inserción en la base de datos $insersion = "insert into tabla (id_usuario, un_dato_varchar, otro_dato_varchar) values ('$id_usuario' , hola, hola);"; esta bien esto? según yo el valor devuelto por mysqli_result es un string pero no estoy seguro y debería ser un entero ya que el id_user de la base de datos es un entero. Simplemente quiero crear la inserción a la base desde php

Comment: Como ya dije, lo más seguro en ese caso sería usar consultas preparadas, así, en el método para enviar el dato de la variabe `$id_usuario` le indicas que es un entero. Y, si lo quieres hacer directamente, lo cual no te recomiendo por motivos de seguridad, en ese consulta directa, lo que determinaría si es un entero o no es la forma en que escribas la consulta, para los enteros, no debes poner el dato entre comillas simples, sino sin comillas, algo así: `insert into tabla (id_usuario, un_dato_varchar, otro_dato_varchar) values ($id_usuario , 'hola', 'hola');"`, y, aunque lo pongas con ...

Comment: ... comillas, el manejador hará la conversión a entero, no hay problema con eso, aunque mientras más riguroso seas escribiendo tu código mejor, así que, los enteros sin comillas y punto. Aparte de eso, este tipo de cosas ni siquiera deberías hacerla por PHP, en las BD existen los `TRIGGER` que sirven para automatizar este tipo de situaciones. Lanzando un `TRIGGER AFTER INSERT` en la tabla A podrás insertar esos datos o parte de ellos en una tabla B de forma automática y transparente, sin ninguna intervención por parte del usuario y sin ningún código PHP.

Answer (score 0):

MySql posee funciones para modificar los tipos de datos, tales como [CAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) o [CONVERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert), sin embargo, considerando que se desea obtener un "Integer" puedes usar operador matemático para forzar la salida de tu consulta a un valor numérico:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID_USUARIOS + 1
    FROM USUARIOS
    WHERE NOMBRE_USUARIO = '$autores';";
```